# Display different survey End messages in LimeSurvey

Tags: survey, surveymonkey, limesurvey

Lime survey has one welcome message and one Ending message. Is it possible to display different ending messages based on the information user submit during survey?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Usage of Expression Manager.

{If(GENDER=="M","Hello boy",if(GENDER=="F","Hello girl",""))}

If you have a question title GENDER.

Look at manual : https://manual.limesurvey.org/Expression_Manager#Tailored_Questions.2C_Answers.2C_and_Reports

Comment: Thanks Denis Chenu. It Helped Me.

Answer (score 0):

For more versatility, you can embed Expression manager in the HTML of the end message.

So, something like this which would display one of two div elements depending on the answer to a question with code "Q1".

```
<div style="display:{if(Q1 == '1', 'block', 'none')};">
    <h2>Heading for Q1 == '1'</h2>
    <p>Some more text for the end message...</p>
</div>
<div style="display:{if(Q1 == '2', 'block', 'none')};">
    <h2>Heading for Q1 == '2'</h2>
    <p>Some more text for the end message...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks tpartner. It gives me different idea to add conditions as a beginner in limesurvey. It helped